# How to solve memory error while filtering data between 2 lists

Tags: python

I wrote a simple code that would filter between 2 lists and combine dictionaries by id from both lists and then write that into another file. But whatever I do I keep getting Memory error.

My code:

```
import ast

with open('fileMain.js') as f:
    content = f.read()
    fileMain = ast.literal_eval(content) 

with open('fileItems.js') as f:
    content = f.read()
    fileItems = ast.literal_eval(content) 


for x in fileMain:
    for y in fileItems:
        if x.get('id') == y.get('id'):
            x['new'] = y 


with open("allData.js", 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(fileMain))
```

fileMain and fileItems equal to 2.5GB on disc and I am using 64-bit version.

Data structure:

fileMain.js

```
[
//Objects with the same ID are not necessarily next to one another.
  {
    "ID": 30574062,
    "anotherNumber": "52,3",
    "color": "red"
  },
  {
    "ID": 30574062,
    "anotherNumber": "13",
    "color": "yellow"
  },
  {
    "ID": 30574063,
    "anotherNumber": "60,6",
    "color": "blue"
  },
  ...
]
```

fileItems.js

```
[
//Objects with the same ID are not necessarily next to one another.
  {
    ID: 30574062,
    number: 28234702,
    place: London,
  },
  {
    ID: 30574063,
    number: 45232502,
    place: Paris,
  },
  ...
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
  {
    ID: 30574062,
    number: 28234702,
    place: London,
    data: [
      {
       "anotherNumber": "52,3",
       "color": "red"
      },
      {
       "anotherNumber": "13",
       "color": "yellow"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    ID: 30574063,
    number: 45232502,
    place: Paris,
    data: [
      {
        "anotherNumber": "60,6",
        "color": "blue"
      },
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: open both file at once and read the data in chunks

Comment: Use an actual database instead of `.js` files.

Comment: @Himanshuman Wouldn't that cause other problems?

Comment: If the data is guaranteed to be in `id` order on disk, you could indeed iterate through the two files in parallel as Himanshuman suggests (you'd need to iterate through them at different speeds to keep them in sync).  But if it's in arbitrary order, you want a database to allow you to access arbitrary parts of each file without having to read through the whole thing.

Comment: The alternative would be to read through one file all the way through and read through the other file in its entirety for each line (so N^2), which will be extremely slooooow for 2.5GB of data!

Comment: @Samwise No, sadly `id` are not in order. I came to the same conclusion of reading fileMain into memory and then going throught fileItems, but even reading fileMain produces a memory error.

Comment: Dealing efficiently with datasets larger than memory is what databases are good for. You can use a streaming parser to get the data info memory a piece at a time to load it into your database, then have the database do the indexing for efficient joins.

Comment: How much memory do you have? Could that data fit into memory at all? Have you tried reading the files with `json` instead of `literal_eval`? Also, you definitely want to convert the first file to a `dict` mapping IDs to lists of elements.

Comment: @Mogma seriously, use a database.  It will be some work to learn a new thing, but you have reached the point where that is necessary.  The job will also be easier if you can go back to the original source of this data and have it written out in a more portable form (e.g. CSV), but the main thing is that you're going to have to learn how to use a database in order to be able to do this type of join on large quantities of data.

Comment: @Samwise Hoped i could have done this last step without some complications. But if there is no other option ill use the database. Since i am really new to python, by database u mean mySQl, firebase... stuff like that, there is no python specific database. Also do u recommend where i should start

Comment: I'd suggest using sqlite since that comes with Python and basically admins itself.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: @Samwise So long story short is that i add some data to sqlite and then tell it how to order/filter itself and then retirieve the data